# Can we create Business Network Card using already created fabric identity from database?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

We have implement blockchain application using fabric + fabric java sdk. Currently, We are storing fabric identity(private key + certificate) in off-chain database. Now, We are considering to migrate application using Hyperledger Composer.

As we already have created fabric identity into database, Can we create Business Network Card at runtime using private key and certificate from database?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your users were created with the Fabric CA - then yes there is a specific Hyperledger Composer CLI command to do just what you want.  The command is `composer identity bind`. The command is documented [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/composer.identity.bind.html) and [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/managing/identity-bind.html).  But unfortunately the documentation and examples are incomplete.  (I will follow up to get them corrected.)

On the composer identity bind command itself you need to add the `-e certfilename` parameter, and after that you need to use `composer card create ...` to create a Business Network Card for the user.

Comment: Thank You. It would be very helpful if you can update me once document is completed.